# Angular component vs model typescript classes

Tags: angular, typescript

I see in many examples that there are `models` created manually for components, specifically to model the data, but the component has already a `ts` class additionally to the `html` and `css` data.

Isn't `data modeling` also part of the component's job? Isn't this the role of the `component's` `ts class`?
Why would you add a separate `model` class and refer it in the `component's` `ts class`?

Comment: *A component controls a patch of screen called a view*. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components

Comment: I get it, that's why it has the `html` / `css` resources, but It feels like it contains also the `model`, i.e. `LoremComponent` typescript class from the `lorem.component.ts` file, that is decorated with the info about the `view` resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will typically use models to pass data to/from the server and these may be shared across different components via a service.

As a simple example you may have a two views (components) for data in the database. One is a list of all the items in the database (say Users) and the other is an add/edit view. You would have something like a UserService service with functions like GetUser, UpdateUser, CreateUser which all return or act on one or more User models.

For more complex datasets you may choose to have a stripped down "list" model e.g. UserListModel and a regular UserModel so that you're not pulling back mountains of data for a summarised list. But for simpler data re-usability is key. And creating models just makes life easy, especially if you're using something like TypeWriter (in Visual Studio) to automatically create typescript versions of your server-side DTOs, Entities etc which saves a lot of time and ensures that your server-side and client-side code stays synchronised and also reduces development overhead.

**EDIT**
As per your comment - it's not a ModelComponent it's just a model/class and should look something like:

```
export class UserModel  { 
    public  userName: string;
    public  email: string;
    public  firstName: string;
    public  lastName: string;
}
```

You would then utilise a UserService user.service.ts to access instances of the UserModel in both components e.g.:

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(
         private http: HttpClient, 
         @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {}

 getUser(userId:number): Observable<UserModel> {
    return this.http.get<UserModel>(this.baseUrl + 'api/users/get/' + userId);
  }

 getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserModel[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/users/list');
  }
}
```

Then you would inject your UserService into both components e.g:

```
export class UserListComponent implements NgOnit{

  public users: UserModel[];

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
         this.users = users;
    });
  };
}



export class UserComponent implements NgOnit{

  public user: UserModel;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUser(/*some userId probably from route*/).subscribe(user => {
         this.user = user;
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: In the example that you gave, I would have an user `component` with the corresponding `UserComponent` class, which I would use in both views or in the service. Why have a different `ModelComponent` class?

Comment: It's not a ModelComponent - it's a Model - it's just an exported typescript class - not a component.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to write `UserModel` class.

Comment: You would have two components in my example - e.g. user-list.component and user-edit.component both would act on one or more UserModel models via the UserService which would be injected into both components

Comment: Exactly, why wouldn't these 2 components both act on one or more `UserComponent` instance? Why have another class (UserModel) that is mapped 1-1 to the `UserComponent` class that is already part of the `user.component.ts`?

Comment: UserModel is not a component, are you using a service e.g. user.service.ts to get data in and out of your database?

Comment: I understand `UserModel` is not an `angular component`, it's a new typescript class that models the `user`. From what I see, this is also what the `UserComponent` typescript class from inside the `user.component.ts` does. So why have both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201134/discussion-between-rob-and-hdoradu).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you ave a register component where you refer to the user model, you may have a login component where you also refer to that model. So creating a separate model class is a good practice for code reusability ;)

Comment: Can't I refer to the `UserComponent` class from the `user.component.ts` in both `login` and `register` components? Why do I need an additional `UserModel` class in a separate `user.model.ts` giving that it would be one to one to the `UserComponent` ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the same data model in many places as we need. With Typescript, we can check the type of any property defined inside a service or component or guards or even directives. So the same type of data [or data type] is used at multiple places which will ensure we are not making any coding mistakes with properties.

If you are defining a complex object in your component as of type any, you are losing IntelliSense and type safety. If you define the complex type as an interface or class inside the component, it's scope is limited to that component. There could be some scenarios like that, but if you define models in a separate central location, you can import that into other classes, making sure the code is type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the logic is intended to be used only inside a single component, it's a good practice to separate a "business" logic from the view logic, you just simplify the component code by that. If you move all the logic which isn't related to the view to a service, you can mush easily test that logic, and it's a huge advantage. See also [Delegate complex component logic to services](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services) section of the Angular style guide.